# Single command from batch file with sqlplus not working in some cases

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I have the following command in a batch file.

```
set tableName=%1
select count(1) from %tableName% where to_char(DATEVALUE,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')^>(select to_char(max(DATEVALUE),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from FOO_TABLE); | sqlplus !connectionString!
```

This statement doesn't work. I can see that it connects to the database and then disconnects. But the following works:

```
select count(1) from %tableName% where to_char(DATEVALUE,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')=(select to_char(max(DATEVALUE),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from FOO_TABLE); | sqlplus !connectionString!
```

I am guessing the problem could be with the `greater than >` symbol. I tried `^>`,`>` and `\>`. None of them works. How can I get this sql statement to work.

(I have connectionString already set in my batch file in earlier lines).

The output in the command line is

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database ... (more db info)

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database ... (more db info)
```

Comment: Perhaps there aren't any rows in your table that have a date greater than any dates in the FOO_TABLE? What happens when you run the query manually (i.e. connect to sqlplus yourself and run the query)? Also, what is the name of the table you're passing in? If it's FOO_TABLE, then I wouldn't expect any rows to be returned!

Comment: `tableName` I am passing is different. In the `=` case, I am getting a `count 0` as result. I am expecting the same in the `>` case too as there are no rows with date greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to escape the `^` escape character as well; depending on exactly how you're running this, either:

```
... where to_char(DATEVALUE,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')^^>(select ...
```

or

```
... where to_char(DATEVALUE,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')^^^>(select ...
```

In a batch file where the query is echoed and piped the triple-escape works:

```
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@set connectionString=x/y@z
@set tableName=bar
@echo select count(1) from %tableName% where to_char(DATEVALUE,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')^^^>(select to_char(max(DATEVALUE),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from FOO_TABLE); | sqlplus !connectionString!
```

Running that batch script shows the statement being run (and erroring in my case with ORA-00942, which is expected). With a single or double `^` it has nothing to run at the SQL prompt and a file is created instead, which seems to be what you're seeing.